# wso2 identity server 5.1 custom authenticator error in project dependency

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I have written a Custom authentication in `wso2 identity server 5.1`, when compiling project, I get this error. I can't found any sample for `is5.1` custom authentication, and use `pom.xml` from `org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authenticator.basicauth_5.0.7`:

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.ren.wso2.identity.application.authenticator:Basic-Custom-Authenticator:2.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\projects\rayCasExt\trunk\BasicCustomAuthenticator\pom.xml) has 4 errors
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.identity.base:jar is missing. @ line 67, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.identity.core:jar is missing. @ line 71, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework:jar is missing. @ line 83, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common:jar is missing. @ line 91, column 21
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

my pom.xml is:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.wso2.carbon.identity</groupId>
        <artifactId>application-authenticators</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ren.wso2.identity.application.authenticator</groupId>
    <artifactId>Basic-Custom-Authenticator</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>WSO2 Carbon - BasicCustomAuthenticator Identity Application Authenticator</name>

    <repositories>
<!--
        Before adding ANYTHING in here, please start a discussion on the dev list.
        Ideally the Axis2 build should only use Maven central (which is available
        by default) and nothing else. We had troubles with other repositories in
        the past. Therefore configuring additional repositories here should be
        considered very carefully.
-->
<!--
        <repository>
            <id>wso2­nexus</id>
            <name>WSO2 internal Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
-->
        <repository>
            <id>wso2.releases</id>
            <name>WSO2 internal Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>wso2.snapshots</id>
            <name>WSO2 Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.utils</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.base</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.core.services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>basic-custom-authenticator</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
                        <Private-Package>
                            com.ren.identity.application.authenticator.custom.internal
                        </Private-Package>
                        <Import-Package>
                            javax.servlet.http; version="${imp.pkg.version.javax.servlet}",

                            org.apache.commons.logging; version="${commons-logging.osgi.version.range}",
                            org.apache.commons.lang; version="${commons-lang.wso2.osgi.version.range}",

                            org.osgi.framework; version="${osgi.framework.imp.pkg.version.range}",
                            org.osgi.service.component; version="${osgi.service.component.imp.pkg.version.range}",

                            org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.*;
                            version="${carbon.identity.package.import.version.range}",
                            org.wso2.carbon.identity.base; version="${carbon.identity.package.import.version.range}",
                            org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.model;
                            version="${carbon.identity.package.import.version.range}",
                            org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util;
                            version="${carbon.identity.package.import.version.range}",

                            org.wso2.carbon.user.api; version="${carbon.user.api.imp.pkg.version.range}",
                            org.wso2.carbon.user.core; version="${carbon.kernel.package.import.version.range}",
                            org.wso2.carbon.user.core.service; version="${carbon.kernel.package.import.version.range}",
                            org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util; version="${carbon.kernel.package.import.version.range}",
                            org.wso2.carbon.utils.multitenancy; version="${carbon.kernel.package.import.version.range}"
                        </Import-Package>
                        <Export-Package>
                            !com.ren.identity.application.authenticator.custom.internal,
                            com.ren.identity.application.authenticator.custom.*
                            version="2.0-SNAPSHOT"
                        </Export-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Anyone can help me. What I have missed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try

```
<version>5.0.7</version>
```

inside the dependency tags of the 4 dependencies mentioned in the error message? Seems like those versions are not mentioned in the parent pom or the parent pom is not linked properly.